# Unity returns error when using GameJolt Unity API

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine

I'm making game in Unity and i want to publish it on GameJolt. I'm using Gamejolt Unity API[Unity API](https://gamejolt.com/games/unity-api/15887) beacuse now i can use Gamjolt's Trophies etc. I don't know why but when i'm using
GameJolt.API.GameJoltAPI.HasSignedInUser it returns error:

> Assets\Scripts\MainMenuScripts_Play_Button\PlayButtonScript.cs(10,30): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GameJoltAPI.HasSignedInUser'

PlayButtonScript.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GameJolt;

public class PlayButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isSignedIn = GameJolt.API.GameJoltAPI.HasSignedInUser;

    void Start() { // Shows GameJolt's Login Screen on start
         GameJolt.UI.GameJoltUI.ShowSignIn();       
    }

    public void onPlayClick() { //
        float random = Random.Range(1, 5);
        Debug.Log(random.ToString());
        SceneManager.LoadScene(random.ToString(), LoadSceneMode.Single);
           
    }
}
```

If you want another scripts or something just ask.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API but it looks like you just need to remove the `()` because the item is a bool, not a method you can call.

Comment: When i deleted `()` it still retruns error but thanks for quick answer!

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `GameJoltAPI.Instance.HasSignedInUser`.

```
var isSignedIn = GameJoltAPI.Instance.HasSignedInUser;
```

Or

```
var isSignedIn = null != GameJoltAPI.Instance.CurrentUser;
```

The error message indicates that `GameJolt.API.GameJoltAPI` is a *type*, not an instance.

A brief glance at the GameJolt documentation implies that most of the API methods & properties are accessed through a singleton, `GameJoltAPI.Instance`.

```
namespace GameJolt.API
{
   class GameJoltAPI
   {
      public static GameJoltAPI Instance {...}
   }
}
```

I suggest reading through the tutorial at https://infectedbytes.github.io/gj-unity-api/tutorial.html .

Comment: Thanks so much for your Error Explanation! This gave me idea. I used "GameJolt.API.GameJoltAPI.HasSignedInUser" this was in documentation but i should use
"GameJolt.API.GameJoltAPI.Instance.HasSignedInUser" just needed added .Instance

Comment: @Empezeeet Glad to help. :)